# two versions of changing data.frame colnames

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanted to change colnames in my data.frame but the initial attempt failed. After some research I found out how it works, but I am still confused why the first attempt did not work out. Maybe someone can explain to me why?

```
#works not
exdf <- mtcars
colnames(exdf)
colnames(exdf[,-c(1, 2)]) <- paste("prefix", colnames(exdf[,-c(1, 2)]), sep="")
colnames(exdf)


#works
exdf <- mtcars
colnames(exdf)
colnames(exdf)[-c(1, 2)] <- paste("prefix", colnames(exdf)[-c(1, 2)], sep="")
colnames(exdf)
```

Comment: The object created is `exdf`

Comment: If you assign attributes to a subset, you don't assign them to the whole object. And you don't even assign the subset. Your second attempt works because there you assign to a subset of the names.

Comment: okay I get it, but why is `colnames(exdf)[-c(1, 2)]` not returning a temporary object, but `exdf[,-c(1, 2)]` is?